# Laravel file uploads failing when file size is larger than 2mb

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I launched an early beta site yesterday. It's vrep.io and I faced a strange problem. When uploading images (user avatars) larger than 2mb laravel validator returns "validation.uploaded" error message.

validator code:

```
protected function basicValidator( array $data ) {
    return Validator::make( $data, [
        'name'        => 'required|min:2|max:255',
        'occupation'  => 'max:255',
        'avatar'      => 'mimes:jpeg,png,gif|dimensions:min_width=500,min_height=500|max:8000',
        'drop-avatar' => 'in:1,0',
    ],
        [
            'avatar.mimes'      => 'Uploaded file format should be jpeg, jpg, png or gif.',
            'avatar.dimensions' => 'Image should have minimum 500x500px dimensions.',
            'avatar.max'        => 'Maximum allowed file size is 6 MB.',
        ] );
}
```

I changed the current php.ini file parameters:

```
upload_max_filesize   100M
post_max_size         100M
memory_limit          256M
```

It's running on AWS EC2 instance. UBUNTU 16.04 and Nginx.

I have also made changes in nginx config file:

```
$ sudo vim /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

client_max_body_size 100m;
```

Restarted nginx and php and even restarted the whole web server. No effect. Still the same error when uploading files larger than 2mb.

p.s. I run homestead locally and file uploads work without any issues. The problem is only on production server.

What did I miss there?

Comment: Can you add your validation code and the complete error please?

Comment: I have added the validator code and the whole error message is "validation.uploaded"

Comment: I think you are making changes in wrong file...there are 2 php configuration files

Answer (score 6):

I do not know how but even if I am searching for an answer the whole day I am finally finding solution in a few minutes after posting here. There's some magic going on on SO. 
So I was editing the wrong php.ini file. I was checking which php ini file was used like this via ssh:

```
$ php --ini
```

But it was showing the wrong file there. Actual configuration file was different for some reason.

Now I dumped php info:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Found the actual config file and everything works. Hope this will help somebody.

Comment: You saved me so much time

Comment: Oh my God! I had the exact same problem as you did. I edited the nginx config files and the php.ini files, all to no avail. I got frustrated and decided to ask my own question on SO, and then right before publishing it, your question was suggested to me. I can't believe I was simply editing the wrong php.ini file! Thank you for posting this solution. I am so grateful because I've spent almost 2 days trying to fix this problem!

Comment: You saved my day... why is it only 2mb by default 

Answer (score 1):

sometimes you install php-fpm and must change specific ini for it.
better way for find location a file is "locate" command :

```
$ locate php.ini

/etc/php5/cgi/php.ini
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini
/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini
```

now if you install php-fpm must change php.ini in fpm folder.

Comment: Thank you! I kept changing the one in the cli folder (/etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini) instead of the one in the fpm folder (/etc/php/8.1/fpm/php.ini).